# Get the exact time using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, time

I have created a kivy app, where if time turns 8pm(20 in 24 hour format), then one function will be called. If I use datetime module,it takes time from device. That means,we can manually change the time. If we manually change the time, it effects my code.  So, I used worldtimeapi and ntplib to get the time, but this takes too long to get the time. Is there any other way to get time (other than device's time) faster ??

Comment: can you provide some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: you can try pulling it from `time.gov`